# Java classpath ordering inconsistent between docker hosts

Tags: java, docker, classpath, classloader, urlclassloader

I'm running a Java service in a Docker image which does something like this:

`java -server -cp 'libs/*'`

Strangely, I found that it would start on my local machine, but not on the dev server, where it would give a `NoSuchMethodError`.

After some digging I found that there were both version 2.0 and 2.1 of JPA in the libs dir. While that in itself is a problem (and easy to fix), it doesn't explain the inconsistency, so I decided to print out:

```
(ClassLoader.getSystemClassLoader() as URLClassLoader).urLs
    .forEach(::println) // kotlin
```

Where I found that the order of libs was different on both machines. It was, however, consistent between subsequent runs of the image on the same machine, so not random.

Though I now know why the image wouldn't start on the dev server, and I can fix the problem at hand, it does leave me wondering: why is this order not consistent across Docker hosts? Isn't reproducibility and consistency one of the main points of Docker? Could the ordering of the classpath depend on finicky things such as IP, hostname, or mounted host dirs (in unrelated locations)?

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this and noticed that the JVM uses a method of resolving wildcards on the classpath that does not provide any ordering guarantees.

See that it uses a [call to readdir](https://github.com/openjdk/jdk/blob/6bab0f539fba8fb441697846347597b4a0ade428/src/java.base/share/native/libjli/wildcard.c#L209) to iterate over the contents represented by the wildcard and that [readdir](https://www.man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readdir.3.html#NOTES) does not guarantee any particular order:

> The order in which filenames are read by successive calls to readdir() depends on the filesystem implementation; it is unlikely that the names will be sorted in any fashion.

You can avoid the ordering issues by explicitly ordering the jars on the classpath rather than using a wildcard. In our case we removed the duplicate jar before we discovered the specific difference in the host systems that yielded different results from readdir.